# How to prevent RDP users from accessing server's hard drives?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am using software from [2X](http://www.2x.com) to publish apps via RDS. I have enabled Drive Redirection so remote users can save files to their own local drives, but I want to disable remote users' access to server's drive. How shall I do this?
Running Win Server 2008 R2. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As long as the users aren't given excessive rights to the server computer they're going to have exceedingly limited access to write on the server computer-- basically to the user profile and subfolders there. If you've giving them more rights then you're going to be fighting a losing battle.

Attempting to remove the users' ability to write to their profile directories is going to end in heartburn for you, likely with applications not functioning properly.

The built-in OS filesystem permissions are going to take care of you and prevent users from blowing-up the server computer. Aside from that, it sounds like a management problem and not a technical problem-- users should save where they're told to.

Edit:

By all means, go ahead and use something "cosmetic" like [the Group Policy setting suggested by Greg](https://serverfault.com/users/20701/greg-askew) because it might make things a bit "cleaner", but don't grant users excessive rights irrespective of the "visibility" of the drive letters.

Answer (score 3):

It is done the same way you would with a workstation.  Use the following group policies:

"Hide these specified drives in My Computer"

"Prevent access to drives from My Computer"

Comment: This is a good start, but both these policies are simple to get around. (By using a command prompt, for example.) Microsoft's explanation of these group policies explains this. `http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/`  TLDR: Use ACLs